# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with median ranks instead of traditional empirical distribution function

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, ranks, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I know that Kolmogorov-Smirnov test uses the empirical distribution function of the sample studied $\widehat{F}(X_i) = \frac{i}{n}$ and then measures the adequacy of function $\widehat{F}$ to function $F$.

In reliability, it is common to use the median ranks method (also known as Benard's approximation) instead of the traditional empirical distribution function, arguing that for small data samples, it's a more accurate approximation of the distribution.
Basically, it consists in calculating $\widehat{F}(X_i)=\frac{i-0.3}{n+0.4}$

My question is therefore : can I use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test approximating the distribution $\widehat{F}$ with Benard's approximation instead of empirical distribution function ?

In particular, it seems that the test relies on the fact that $\sqrt{n} \left\| \widehat{F} - F \right\|$ with $\widehat{F}$ being the traditional empirical distribution function, not the Benard's approximation. I wonder if the mathematical demonstration and properties (unbiased estimation, etc.) still holds if replacing it by Benard's approximation?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People create their own estimators all the time for various reasons, and it is fine to do so and explore/derive/prove their properties. However, it is a mistake to assume that an exotic estimator has the same properties as the usual estimator just because it estimates the same quantity. Consequently, you are free to create this KS-style test and explore/derive/prove its properties, but it is a mistake to believe that the test statistic and p-value will behave the same as the usual KS test. You are, after all, creating a new hypothesis test.

[An early question of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/419146/247274) is related to this. I wanted to run the usual t-test but estimate the variance in a different way. The accepted answer notes that the test properties will change (though it does not seem that the changes will be so dramatic).

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Consequently, I guess that it would therefore be incorrect to use the table of critical values of the KS test in this case?